# Computer intensive system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I have a really computer intensive system of ODEs to solve numerically, I have written the general form below:
Hi all, I have a difficult ODE system that I am unsure Mathematica can handle:

---

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[u] == (a)*z[u],                                                                                                                
           y'[u] == (b/Exp[u] + c/Exp[3 u]) z[u],                                                                                                                        
           z'[u] == (a/2)*(1 - 2*x[u]) - (b/Exp[u] + c/Exp[3 u]) y[u],                                                                                                   
           x[N[14 Log[10]]] == 0, z[N[14 Log[10]]] == 0,                                                                                                                 
           y[N[14 Log[10]]] == 0}, {x, y, z}, {u, N[2 Log[10]],                                                                                                          
           N[14 Log[10]]}, {a, b, c}, MaxSteps -> 10^10]                                                                                                                 

Out[1]= ParametricFunction[<>]

In[2]:= Table[{a, b, c,                                                                                                                                                  
           pfun[a, b, c][[1]][N[2 Log[10]]]}, {a, {0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.1, 1,                                                                                             
            10, 100, 1000, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 10^9, 10^10, 10^11,                                                                                             
            10^12, 10^13, 10^14, 10^15}}, {b, {0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.1, 1, 10,                                                                                             
            100, 1000, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 10^9, 10^10, 10^11,                                                                                                 
            10^12, 10^13, 10^14, 10^15}}, {c, {0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.1, 1, 10,                                                                                             
            100, 1000, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 10^9, 10^10, 10^11,                                                                                                 
            10^12, 10^13, 10^14, 10^15}}]
```

---

Mathematica is having a hard time running this for the largest values written; if anyone has any suggestions on dealing with this in the large $a,b,c$ limit I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If you look at the solutions, you'll see they oscillate very quickly, particularly as $a$ increases.  This is what makes it hard for `NDSolve` (and probably any other ODE solver) to deal with.

Comment: Exactly @ChrisK, though there must be some tricks known for such a problem?

Comment: So far, the best I can come up with is solving analytically in the asymptotic limit for $a\ll b,c$ and $a \gg b,c$, which only leaves the case where $a,b,c$ are all large

Comment: Do you really need the exact value of `x[N[2 Log[10]]]`?  Given the rapid oscillations in `x`, I'd think that it would be extremely sensitive to changes in the parameters (and perhaps numerical errors).  That is, your coarse grid of parameter values would basically be sampling from a distribution of `x` values.

Comment: I do indeed, its an important value, I'm guessing the problem is just too much to compute, perhaps I could up the maxsteps and put in on a cluster, I want to know your thoughts

Comment: Try `Plot[pfun[a, 10^3, 10^3][[1]][N[2 Log[10]]], {a, 1000, 1001}]` to see just how sensitive `x[N[2 Log[10]]]` is to the value of parameter `a`, even for these relatively small values.  Although I don't know the physical interpretation of your problem, Richard Hamming's quote that "the purpose of computing is insight, not numbers" seems like it might apply.  Good luck!